# Will there be difference of performance using different deep learning implementations, when the settings are the same

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, torch

I have used Torch, Tensorflow and sknn, and found major differences in their mechanism design, syntax, environment requirement, performance in terms of speed, however, I want to know if there is any difference among these libraries when the neural network have the exact same settings?

In another word, will the performance (in terms of, say, accuracy in classification tasks) be difference using different implementations to build the network, when the network itself has the same settings (number of layers, type of layers, dropout, activations, objective functions etc.) ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: if all the network structure including their parameters and hyper parameters are the same the answer is no. you'll not have any difference in term of accuracy or error measurement. the only difference is by computation efficiency which depends on library implementation

Comment: @Feras Wow, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is any difference among these libraries when the neural network have the exact same settings?

Sure. See [ConvNet Benchmark](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks) for example.

There are always minor differences how to compute things, even if you compute the same. For example, `x^4` can be computed as `tmp=(x*x); tmp*tmp` or as `x*(x*(x*x))`. Or the matrix multiplication ijk vs ikj (see [my article](https://martin-thoma.com/matrix-multiplication-python-java-cpp/) for more). Compiler optimizations might also be quite important.

> In another word, will the performance (in terms of, say, accuracy in classification tasks) be difference using different implementations to build the network, when the network itself has the same settings (number of layers, type of layers, dropout, activations, objective functions etc.) ?

That is a different question than speed. However, due to numerical issues, you might still get some different results. However, they should not be significant.

### See also

- [Comparison of deep learning software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_deep_learning_software)
- [deepframeworks](https://github.com/zer0n/deepframeworks/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for the links!  Besides computation efficiency, is there difference in accuracy,  for different libraries in the same settings?

Comment: @Jason You're welcome. Usually, people make two posts if they have two questions to avoid that only one gets answered. (And it is also wanted to have rather two posts). Please take my answer about the accuracy with a grain of salt; I didn't actually try it. So I'm only 99% sure that this is correct.